# Нужно помочь разобраться, что не так в коде

Tags: c++

Имеется вот такое задание: Напишите программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры непустой массив целых чисел, и печатает число локальных максимумов (элемент является локальным максимумом, если он не имеет соседей, больших, чем он сам).

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Vedite pazmepHoct macuva: ";
  int n = 0;
  cin >> n;
  int arr[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "arr[" << i << "] = ";
    cin >> arr[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        cout << arr[i] << '\n';
      }
    } else if (i == n - 1) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
        cout << arr[i] << '\n';
      }
    } else {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1] && arr[i] > arr[i - 1])
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
  }
  cin.get();
  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: в коде "не так" отступы

Comment: А что не так в коде?

Comment: Сколько локальных максимумов в массиве `[1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: @Igor Очевидно, что три. По определению

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Дa. Но не по коду.

Comment: int arr[n]; выражение должно иметь константное значение

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо *печатает число локальных максимумов*, так что надо просто посчитать это число и вывести, а не выводить сами числа.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Vedite pazmepHoct macuva: ";
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
        }

    int max_count = 0;

    if (arr[0] >= arr[1]) max_count++;

    if (arr[n - 1] >= arr[n - 2]) max_count++;

    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] >= arr[i + 1] && arr[i] >= arr[i - 1]) max_count++;

    cout << max_count;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Выделенную память нужно освобождать. 2. При `n==1` работать не будет. 3. Не соответствует определению локальных максимумов по версии ТС

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ладно с освободжением (зачем? программа на этом закончена? память освободится автоматом) и n==1, но почему условие максимума не то? Сказано же - если соседи не превышают ("не имеет соседей, больших"), так что неравенство нестрогое.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Mikhailo Что произойдет на этой строке `if (arr[0] >= arr[1]) max_count++;` при `n==1`? И первоначальный код у вас был на строгое неравенство

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Я же сказал — ладно с памятью и случаем `n==1`, но вы их опять начали пояснять... А неравенство я изменил еще до вашего комментария, насколько я помню.